# Cmake doesn't respect value of CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX

Tags: build, cmake, installation, gnu-make, awesome-wm

I'm trying to install awesome wm from source. So I created a build directory and executed the following command:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PREFIX
```

But `make install` tries to put some of the program files in `/usr/local/share`, which isn't where I want them:

```
> make install
[  3%] Built target generated_sources
[  6%] Built target test-gravity
[  9%] Built target lgi-check
[  9%] Built target version_stamp
[ 29%] Built target generated_icons
[ 31%] Checking for LGI...
Building for Lua 5.3.
Found lgi 0.9.2.
[ 31%] Built target lgi-check-run
[ 35%] Built target generate_awesomerc
[100%] Built target awesome
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Up-to-date: /home/user/.local/bin/awesome
-- Up-to-date: /home/user/.local/bin/awesome-client
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/awesome/lib
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:69 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot make directory "/usr/local/share/awesome/lib": No such
  file or directory


make: *** [Makefile:107: install] Error 1
```

Is there some cmake variable similar to `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` or `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` which I need to specify for `share` data?

Comment: It depends on the project's way to install files, so you need to check `CMakeLists.txt` to get an answer

Comment: What is the value of the variable `PREFIX`?

Comment: @TimothyBrown `PREFIX` is set to `${HOME}/.local`, where I want to install the program.

Comment: personnally I would use `cmake --build build --target install -- DESTDIR=${PREFIX}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have `CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR` for `share` when using the cmake module: include([GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html))

Note: when using `cmake --build build --target install -- DESTDIR=foo`
please read the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX doc

> On UNIX one can use the DESTDIR mechanism in order to relocate the whole installation. DESTDIR means DESTination DIRectory.
>
> WARNING: DESTDIR may not be used on Windows because installation prefix usually contains a drive letter like in C:/Program Files which cannot be prepended with some other prefix.

src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html#variable:CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX